# Arrange menu image

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I am new to html / css.

I want to build a menu html / css for wordpress which have representative images

Image not arrange as they wish ... I only see 3/4 of it

This is the link

http://test.dac-proiect.ro/wp/

This is the css code

```
    .home3
{
background-image: url(img/HOME.png);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: left;
padding-left: 30px;

}
.expertiza
{
background:url(img/HOME.png)no-repeat;
width:186px;
height:48px;
}

.menu
{
list-style-type: none;
}
.menu li
{
display:inline;
}
```

Comment: You see only 3 because there are only 3  edit your wordpress page max number

Comment: I refer to the picture menu ... not seen completely

Answer (score 0):

add `background-position` and `background-size`

```
.home3 {
background-image: url(img/HOME.png);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: left top;/*add this*/
padding-left: 30px;
background-size: 32px 32px;/*add this*/
}

.expertiza {
background: url(img/HOME.png)no-repeat;
width: 186px;
height: 48px;
background-position: left top;/*add this*/
background-size: 32px 32px;/*add this*/
padding-left: 32px;/*add this*/
}
```

[image]

Comment: I understand ... and there is a possibility to view all the pictures?
Look how it looks original image    http://i60.tinypic.com/2nsqfmf.png

Comment: @dcrysty23 add padding-bottom `padding-bottom: 20px;`